# Net::LDAP::Error at /users/sign_in Connection timed out - user specified timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I'm setting up a login with devise_ldap_authentication gem. Sometimes the LDAP server is down and i get the follow error 
"Net::LDAP::Error at /users/sign_in
Connection timed out - user specified timeout".

I tried multiple ways to handle the raised error but i couldn't.

The action controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    begin
      resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      redirect_to root_path
    rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to new_user_session_path, :notice => $!.to_s}
        format.json {render json: $!.to_s}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would like check the connection server and if won't work, authenticate  users with local credentials.